# use alert box for confirmation

Tags: javascript, html

I am allowing myself to send payments to others directly from my node.js app.

I am trying to basically do this:

Once I click the `send payment` button, it should alert me, with a message, are you sure you want to send this payment. and if I click `yes`, then do it, if `cancelled`, then dont. I assume this is a `script` but I'm not sure how to get the `result` of the button click. How can I do this?

```
 <td data-label="SEND PAYMENT"><button>SEND PAYMENT</button></td>     

<script>

if (alertBoxResult === "yes") {
redirect to function
}

</script>
```

something like this. How can I do this?

Comment: How about use a confirm() box for alert instead? `if(confirm('Message')){ doSomething()}`

Comment: Create a custom popup modal with yes no option or from javascript use "confirm " method instead of alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can just use `confirm`:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function()
{
  if (confirm('Are you sure you want to pay?'))
  {
    console.log('Processing payment.');
  }
  else
  {
    console.log('Payment canceled.');
  }
});
```

```html
<button>Pay some money</button>
```

Comment: worked perfect, thank you! Will accept answer when it allows me to!